# R igraph ancestors python

Tags: r, igraph

I have a network like in the diagram. In python there is the ancestors function. When i use it on node 5, it will provide list of nodes 1,2 and 3. what is an equivalent function in igraph R? I tried subcomponent but it didn't work for me.

Also my actual network is quiet long and I don't want to use parent or child function as I don't know degree in every case

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R function is `neighborhood` with `mode="in"`: http://igraph.org/r/doc/neighborhood.html E.g.

```
g1 <- graph(c(1,4, 1,2, 1,3, 3,2, 2,5))
neighborhood(g1, 5, order=vcount(g1), mode="in")[[1]]
# [1] 5 2 1 3
```

This will also include the queried vertex itself, but it is easy to remove that:

```
setdiff(neighborhood(g1, 5, order=vcount(g1), mode="in")[[1]], 5)
# [1] 2 1 3
```

Comment: wont work for me as one of the input parameters in "order". As i mentioned, my actual graph is very long and i dont want to run neighborhood command for every different "order" :(

Comment: why not recursively call `neighborhood` with `mode="in"` and `order=1`?

Comment: @ScottRitchie would it be possible to provide an example code? or to begin with you can use the network above. but dont assume any "order"

Comment: @user2543622: set `order` to the number of vertices.

Comment: @user2543622: I did not include example code first, because you did not, either. You are expected to provide a reproducible example (in the format of code we can run!) in your questions.

Comment: will do next time, and thanks for the answer..what is the purpose of [[1]]? is it to convert list to numeric array?

Comment: You can query multiple vertices, so the result is returned in a list, with one entry for each queried vertex.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `neighborhood` function @GaborCsardi suggested, you can recursively get all the ancestors of a node:

```
# Warning, only works on directed graphs!
ancestors <- function(node, graph) {
  parents <- neighborhood(graph, order=1, nodes=node, mode="in")[[1]][-1]
  if (length(parents) == 0) {
    NULL
  } else {
    theirParents <- unlist(sapply(parents, ancestors, graph))
    unique(c(parents, theirParents))
  }
}
```

And now we can test it on your example graph:

```
> g1 <- graph(c(1,4, 1,2, 1,3, 3,2, 2,5))
> ancestors(5, g1)
[1] 2 1 3
> ancestors(2, g1)
[1] 1 3
> ancestors(1, g1)
NULL
>
```

Comment: This is not actually needed, `neighborhood` is recursive, `order` just gives the limit.